# Postgres xmlelement encoding

Tags: xml, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, internationalization

My postgres database in UTF-8 and client in UTF-8 too.
When i try to:

```
select xmlelement(name pampam, xmlattributes('русский' as "top"));
```

I get back:

```
<pampam top="&#x440;&#x443;&#x441;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x438;&#x439;"/>`
```

But i want get back attribute as is( i.e. in Russian UTF-8), not as `&#x440`....
How i can do this?

---

This is not solve problem, I use xmleliment to construct xml from data get back by queries.
And i can't find another way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be possible.  The values to print are passed to libxml, and that's how it chooses to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not the best solution but this works for me:

```
SELECT xmlparse(CONTENT '<element attribute=''áéíóú´ñÇ`''>value</element>')
```

I get back:

```
<element attribute='áéíóú´ñÇ`'>value</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a character entity to character conversion function, [entity2char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985946/131874):

```
select
    xmlparse(content
        entity2char((
            xmlelement(name pampam, xmlattributes('русский' as "top"))
        )::text)
    );
        xmlparse         
-------------------------
 <pampam top="русский"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used plpythonu to write function using lxml

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xmlelementpy (
              nodename_in varchar,
              nodetext_in text,
              attrname_in varchar [],
              attrvalue_in varchar []
)
RETURNS xml AS
$body$
from lxml import etree
noattr = 0
isxml = 1
if (attrname_in is None) or (attrname_in is None):
    noattr = 1
elif len(attrname_in) <> len(attrvalue_in):
    return None;

newnode = etree.Element(nodename_in)
if nodetext_in is not None:
    try: 
        schema = etree.fromstring(nodetext_in)
    except: 
        newnode.text = nodetext_in
        isxml = 0
    if isxml <> 0:
        newnode.append(etree.XML(nodetext_in))

if noattr <> 1:
    for i in range(len(attrname_in)):
        if (attrvalue_in[i] is not None):
            attrvalue = attrvalue_in[i].decode('UTF-8')
            newnode.set(attrname_in[i], attrvalue)

return etree.tounicode(newnode, pretty_print=True)
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpythonu'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```